# Is there a way to see the Reponses that have been submitted on html+/css page?

Tags: html, css, forms

First question on here so please tell me if I did anything wrong.

Is there a way to see the responses that have been submitted via form? I have made a form but was wondering how I can see the responses that have been submitted.

Here's what I've done:
Sorry for a load of mistakes:)

I really appreciate any help in advance:

````
<html>

    
  <body>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
        body {
          font-family: "", sans-serif;
        }
        
        .sidenav {
          height: 100%;
          width: 0;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 1;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          background-color: #111;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          transition: 0.5s;
          padding-top: 60px;
        }
        
        .sidenav a {
          padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 15px;
          color: #818181;
          display: block;
          transition: 0.3s;
        }
        
        .sidenav a:hover {
          color: #f1f1f1;
        }
        
        .sidenav .closebtn {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 25px;
          font-size: 36px;
          margin-left: 50px;
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
          .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
          .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/home.html">home</a>
          <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/shop.html">shop</a>
          <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/about%20us.html">about us</a>
          <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/contact%20us.html">contact us</a>
          <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/stockists.html">become a stockist</a>
        </div>
        
       
        <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
        
        <script>
        function openNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        }
        
        function closeNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        }
        </script>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
           <style>
           body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
           * {box-sizing: border-box;}
           
           input[type=text], select, textarea {
             width: 100%;
             padding: 12px;
             border: 1px solid #ccc;
             border-radius: 4px;
             box-sizing: border-box;
             margin-top: 6px;
             margin-bottom: 16px;
             resize: vertical;
           }
           
           input[type=submit] {
             background-color: #000000;
             color: white;
             padding: 12px 20px;
             border: none;
             border-radius: 4px;
             cursor: pointer;
           }
           
           input[type=submit]:hover {
             background-color: #45a049;
           }
           
           .container {
             border-radius: 5px;
             background-color: #f2f2f2;
             padding: 20px;
           }
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
           
           <h3> c o n t a c t . </h3>

           <h4> We're more likely to respond by email</h4>
           <p> send us an email :  </p>
           
           <div class="container">
             <form action="/action_page.php">
               <label for="fname">First Name</label>
               <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
           
               <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
               <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
           

               </select>
           
               <label for="subject">Subject</label>
               <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
           
               <input type="submit" value="Submit">
             </form>
           </div>
           
        </body>
  </body>  
</html>```
````

Comment: Where's your action_page.php file? What does it do?

Comment: try `print_r($_POST)` in the action file.

Comment: Have you got a backend where your php file resides? I notice you haven't put php as a tag but that's where you have asked the system to 'go' on submit of the form.

Comment: Hiya! If you needed a bit of context I'm making a shopping website - this page is supposed to let them contact me on the site, and i should be able to see, but I wasn't sure how this would work. I'm an absolute beginner so I'm not really sure how I can go about this :)